# Some folds in k-fold cross-validation containing 0 True/False positives

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network, cross-validation

I am working on a problem of time-series segmentation of sleep sensor data by using U-Net (CNN-based) in a tensorflow(keras) implementation and I am getting some really strange behavior. For a 10-fold cross-validation run, typically 9 folds work as expected, with one or two folds containing 0 positive predictions. I am at a complete loss at this point as to why some of the folds refuse to learn anything and seem to get stuck in a local minima after 1 epoch... I am really looking for ANY input that could point me in the right direction, thanks!

For example I receive:

```
TP=87153
TN=1889185
FP=35217
FN=93021
```

for a typical fold, but in a problematic one:

```
TP=0
TN=1912697
FP=0
FN=191879
```

As you can see, the model predicts no positives for these runs.

Stats for 10 folds; recall/precision is 0.000 for the problematic fold #2 (technically undefined):

| fold | acc | precision | recall | f1 | specificity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.895 | 0.752 | 0.629 | 0.685 | 0.954 |
| 2 | 0.862 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 1.000 |
| 3 | 0.903 | 0.727 | 0.592 | 0.653 | 0.960 |
| 4 | 0.894 | 0.760 | 0.531 | 0.625 | 0.966 |
| 5 | 0.893 | 0.805 | 0.561 | 0.661 | 0.969 |
| 6 | 0.901 | 0.755 | 0.583 | 0.658 | 0.963 |
| 7 | 0.900 | 0.760 | 0.518 | 0.616 | 0.970 |
| 8 | 0.865 | 0.857 | 0.522 | 0.649 | 0.973 |
| 9 | 0.891 | 0.779 | 0.572 | 0.659 | 0.963 |
| 10 | 0.895 | 0.806 | 0.592 | 0.683 | 0.967 |

I have tried these measures with no effect:

1. Reducing the size of the model (# of nodes/feature channels)
2. Reducing the number of convolutional layers in U-Net
3. Balancing the dataset (It is quite unbalanced)
4. Removing dropout layers
5. Upgrading to tensorflow 2.3.
6. Running 10 runs with different randomSeeds, this simply shifts the problem to another fold, and the zero-fold behavior appeared in 7/10 of the runs. This tells me that the error is not data-dependent.
7. Reducing the size of the data-set to give me some clues. This makes the problem worse, and introduces *more* problematic zero-positive folds (up to 5/10), but the problematic folds remain a superset of the problematic folds in the runs with more data, which is further evidence that it is not data-dependent.

A problematic fold's run will have this behavior where the loss starts extremely high and gradually goes down, but val_accuracy and accuracy stay the same (except for the first epoch). I am using ReLu as the activation function, which I think should prevent vanishing gradients(?):

```
Epoch 1/50
397/397 [==============================] - 13s 33ms/step - loss: 0.6851 - accuracy: 0.9010 - val_loss: 0.6777 - val_accuracy: 0.8963
Epoch 2/50
397/397 [==============================] - 12s 30ms/step - loss: 0.6688 - accuracy: 0.9207 - val_loss: 0.6628 - val_accuracy: 0.8963
Epoch 3/50
397/397 [==============================] - 12s 30ms/step - loss: 0.6532 - accuracy: 0.9207 - val_loss: 0.6484 - val_accuracy: 0.8963
Epoch 4/50
397/397 [==============================] - 12s 30ms/step - loss: 0.6381 - accuracy: 0.9207 - val_loss: 0.6345 - val_accuracy: 0.8963
Epoch 5/50
397/397 [==============================] - 12s 30ms/step - loss: 0.6235 - accuracy: 0.9207 - val_loss: 0.6210 - val_accuracy: 0.8963
```

A normal fold's epochs by contrast:

```
Epoch 1/50
397/397 [==============================] - 12s 31ms/step - loss: 0.2710 - accuracy: 0.9195 - val_loss: 0.2063 - val_accuracy: 0.8963
Epoch 2/50
397/397 [==============================] - 12s 31ms/step - loss: 0.1671 - accuracy: 0.9195 - val_loss: 0.1953 - val_accuracy: 0.8963
Epoch 3/50
397/397 [==============================] - 12s 31ms/step - loss: 0.1613 - accuracy: 0.9342 - val_loss: 0.1915 - val_accuracy: 0.9302
Epoch 4/50
397/397 [==============================] - 12s 31ms/step - loss: 0.1582 - accuracy: 0.9436 - val_loss: 0.1867 - val_accuracy: 0.9318
Epoch 5/50
397/397 [==============================] - 12s 31ms/step - loss: 0.1567 - accuracy: 0.9444 - val_loss: 0.1871 - val_accuracy: 0.9316
```

Hyperparameters:

```
validationFraction: 0.33
batchSize: 500
numFolds: 10
numEpochs: 50
```

I would really appreciate any thoughts or anecdotal insights if you have encountered something similar.